# Converting XML Node Names to Uppercase (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt, translate

I have many XSLT stylesheet(s) that transform some XML into a csv file.
The XML files used are generated based on database column names which used to be converted automatically to UPPERCASE when the XML was being built - which can no longer be done (we are no using TSQL-FOR XML to build the XML). The column names are Generally a mixture of uppercase and lowercase letters.
As all Stylesheets currently reference Uppercase column names, the XPath queries are failing.

Instead of going through ALL XSL stylesheets and manually changing the XPath queries to the case of the database column names - which would take most of this year(!)
Is there any way to convert all the XML 'Tag' names to Uppercase, so you can use them in the document?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank You!
Andrew

An example:
The below will generate a csv file with the right about Of rows, but without any data, as the xslt is looking for "STRNAME", when it is stored in The XML as "strName"
my XML:

```
<XMLWRAPPER>
   <STAFFTABLE>
      <ROW>
         <strName>Andrew</strName>
         <strSurname>Smith</strSurname>
         <intuserType>1</intUserType>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <strName>Jackie</strName>
         <strSurname>collins</strSurname>
         <intuserType>2</intUserType>
      </ROW>
    </STAFFTABLE>
  </XMLWRAPPER>
```

and the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">"First Name","Surname","User type"<xsl:text>&#013;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="/XMLWRAPPER/STAFFTABLE/ROW">
        <xsl:value-of select="STRNAME"/>,<xsl:value-of select="STRSURNAME"/>,<xsl:value-of select="INTUSERTYPE"/><xsl:text>&#013;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Depending on your database, making your column names all-uppercase would work too. Another approach could be to run a simple perl script on generated XML to uppercase the tags.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my solution for a solution that can be used even in the case when the names contain non-latin letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 I would use the [**Identity Transformation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e17557) and the [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{
            translate(name(.),
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform will "upper case" elements only, not the attributes. It is easy anyway extend it to attributes just by changing the match pattern of the second template to `*|@*`.

---

As per the comments below and the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate), `translate()` function *is not a sufficient solution for case conversion in all languages.*

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Fortunately, the database naming conventions mean there are no non-ascii characters, so this should be fine!  However, Should this be used as a separate Transformation before running the transformation to the CSV file? or is there a way to incorporate them into one transformation?

Comment: Good (further) question. You can incroporate this, but I think you need a two-pass function.

Comment: Are you able to accomplish that? There is a recent thread about this for which I've provided an exteneded answer. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528783/removing-attributes-from-xslt-and-working-with-result-set/6530068#6530068). Tell me if you need any help. Hope you will accept the answer when satisfied.

Comment: Hi Empo, What do you mean by a two-pass function?

Comment: Thanks Empo, i shall try that out :)

Comment: hi empo, I couldn't get the two-pass function to operate properly with my Report code above - probably down to my limited knowlegde of xslt! I did manage to do it in two separate transformations, which Is how i'm leaving it for now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Andrew you are welcome! I'll try to post here a 2nd answer with the two pass within this evening.

Comment: @Andrew which xslt processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using The XslCompiledTransform class in C#.NET - part of the System.Xml.Xsl namespace. I do not know if this is a Processor on it's own, but I would assume it is similar to MSXML processor, as it appears to only run on windows platforms! [msdn_xslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

Comment: It supports XSLT 1.0 syntax; that means that you will need a node-set function for the two pass, that is, implement something like http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/. Is it feasable for you? Otherwise I think it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

@empo 's solution is the one that can be used if the names consisted only of latin characters. If this isn't the case one can use a similar XSLT 2.0 transformation which replaces the `translate()` function in @empo's solution with the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`upper-case()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-upper-case)**.

Also, if you have just a few sylesheets, it may be much easier to modify the stylesheets themselves to handle mix-cased names:

That is:

**Instead of**

`<xsl:template match="SOMENAME">`

**use**:

```
 <xsl:template 
   match="*['SOMENAME' = translate(., $Lowercase, $Uppercase)]">
```

Comment: You are absolutely right about LATIN - utf8 which is default will not catch all - I live in denmark and the ÆØÅ was not even represented. But then again, the lingual environment seems to be LATIN :)

Comment: @user639175: The `upper-case()` function should provide correct result in most cases. In a few exceptions its results don't match the linguistical expectations of a given language -- see the specification of the function -- linked to in my answer.

Comment: "If this isn't the case" what one can use in XSLT 1.0 (which seems the OP's case)?

Comment: @empo: Extended strings containing all letters considered "lower" and all letters considered "upper" -- or extension function, if all letters from all languages can be expected. Then use these with `translate()`