# Best practice for inserting and deleting elements via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and now i have a rather complicated problem... My input file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
  <outerElement>
    <first>
      <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
    </first>
    <second>
      <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
    </second>
    <third>
      <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
    </third>
  </outerElement>
</doc>
```

The problem occurs with the "second" Element. In the input file it can have one of 3 forms:

```
MISSING

<second>
  <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
</second>

<second missingCause="" />
```

In the output file it should be inserted like the second form. If it was missing before the textElement should indicate it was inserted by the Template and whats important here is it has to be at the second position because i want to validate it against a xsd schema...

Here is my current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- COPY ALL ELEMENTS -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- remove Elements with attribute deleteme -->
  <xsl:template match="outerElement/second[@missingCause='*']" />

  <!-- look if second is there. If not insert -->
  <xsl:template match="outerElement">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(second)">
        <second>
        </second>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Insert Element second -->
  <xsl:template match="outerElement/second">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="not(textElement)">
        <textElement>Inserted by Template</textElement>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If "second" is missing my output file just gets an Element "" but its empty and the last transformation does not get applied. Everything else looks fine while when i have  in the Document i get a warning...

Can someone please help me moving the Element to where it has to be so it is validates to a Schema and make it work in all three cases?

I think my way seems not very good and will end up chaotic because i got several similar Elements to insert / delete like this.

Thanks for reading ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is a generic solution that works for any number of differently named children of `outerElement` and any prefered order between them**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUncertainElName" select="'second'"/>

 <xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|first|second|third|'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="outerElement">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfFirstPass">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "self::*[not(*[name() = $pUncertainElName])
                or
                 *[name()=$pUncertainElName and @missing-cause]]"
         mode="missing"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfFirstPass)/*" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@missing-cause]"/>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="missing">
    <xsl:element name="{$pUncertainElName}">
        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="outerElement" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
     "string-length(substring-before($pOrderedNames,
                                     concat('|', name(), '|')
                                     )
                   )"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </first>
        <second missing-cause="">
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </second>
        <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </third>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <first>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </first>
      <second>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </second>
      <third>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </third>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**When it is applied on this XML document**:

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </first>
        <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </third>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <first>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </first>
      <second>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </second>
      <third>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </third>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**Finally, when the same transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </first>
        <second>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </second>
        <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </third>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**again the same wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <first>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </first>
      <second>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </second>
      <third>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </third>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**Do Note**:

There can be any, unlimited number of differently named children of `outerElement` (not just three), and their order may not be known in advance.

**For example**:

**Given this XML document**:

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </first>
        <second missing-cause="">
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </second>
        <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </third>
        <fourth>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
        </fourth>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**and this order**: forth, second, third, first

**We only have to replace**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|first|second|third|'"/>
```

**with**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|fourth|second|third|first|'"/>
```

**And now the new wanted result is produced**:

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <fourth>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </fourth>
      <second>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </second>
      <third>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </third>
      <first>
         <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </first>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**Explanation**:

1. This is a two-pass transformation.
2. The name of the element that may or maynot be present is specified in the external/global parameter `$pUncertainElName`. For convenience in this explanation we refer to this element as `second`.
3. On the first pass, all children of `outerElement` with the exception of `second` that has the `missing-cause` attribute, are copied "as-is". If the `second` element was absent or had the `missing-cause` attribute, we output a new child of `outerElement` -- the exactly wanted `second` element.
4. In the second pass we sort the children of the `outerElement` produced in the first pass, according to their priority, as specified in another external/global parameter, named `$pOrderedNames` (a name that is left of another name in this string, has higher priority)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer this seems to be what I need to do but i dont get how its working in all aspects.. The first Template is the identity Template thats ok. The Second seems to do some crazy stuff it sets the mode to missing, so the fourth template inserts the element while the third one is deleting the object with missing-cause? - How is the first one working and why there is a Variable in there?

Comment: @DennisIch: This is called *multi-pass processing*. The main idea is that the output of every pass is captured in an xsl:variable and then in the next pass templates are applied on the tree contained in this variable. I guess that you are confused by the use of the `ext:node-set()` extension function -- this is necessary in XSLT 1.0 (not necessary in XSLT 2.0), because of limitations (the infamous RTF datatype) of XSLT 1.0. See for example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529617/36305

Comment: Ok to clarify... The this template where the variable is in the variable itself produces no output but is processed and it does an identity copy and then? Does this second select trigger the "missing" template? I am confused how it jumps from template to template ;( - Wouldn't it be easier/clearer if i store the OuterElement into a variable and use xsl:call-template on it? I could then also create more than one missing variable.

Comment: @DennisIch: I see, you are confused by the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction. Its purpose is to add the missing element in the intermediary result. This can also be done with `xsl:call-templates`. It is more in the spirit of XSLT to use `xsl:apply-templates` and to avoid using `xsl:call-templates`. The former is polymorphic (like invoking a C++ virtual method) and much more powerful than the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your help I think i got it mostly... Most of the Elements i need to add are similar to each other so I think i could use your template as a Base and a make it generic with more params but this does not work as i expected ;). I f the path to the Element i want to add isnt something like outerElement anymore can i use <xsl:param name=pPath value="'outerElement/innerElement'"> to specify the Elements I want to match? I googled but i didnt found and accurate answere it should be possible to use something like match="$pPath" but i dont get the exact syntax and i get errors all the time

Comment: @DennisIch: I strongly recommend that you ask a new, separate question as the comments format is limited/not-convenient for sharing code. Just let me know when the new question is posted and I'll be glad to answer it.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea ;) i posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210155/using-parameters-to-match-elements-inx-xslt

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding how templates work. For what you need to accomplish, it seems that just one template is required (plus the identity template). Try and feedback:

```
<xsl:template match="outerElement[not(second) or second[@missingCause='']]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|first"/>
    <second>
        <textElement>Inserted by Template</textElement>
    </second>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="third"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Its working as expected thanks :) - why is the first select like "@*|first" and the last select="third"? Is there any way to automate where this element is put in the xml so it fits into a xsd schema or do i have to do all of them myself?

Comment: With first select we ensure that templates are applied to outerElement attributes. I don't understand the second question.

Comment: ah ok :) - For the second Question.. I have a Schema and in this Schema some elements are (0-1) and some of this elements are mandatory to my application. So i get data where this elements are missing and i want to put em all in with XSL. Is there a way to tell the XSL, that it has to order the Elements i insert in order to fit the schema so it validates. There are some Elements with a huge number of children and applying the template one b one in order would be hard work because i have to take every element that can be there into account.