# Using Parameters to match elements inx XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I got the following template from another post..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="pUncertainElName" select="'second'"/>
<xsl:param name="pParentPath" select="'outerElement/innerElement'" />
<xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|first|second|third|'"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="outerElement/innerElement">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfFirstPass">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "self::*[not(*[name() = $pUncertainElName])
                or
                *[name()=$pUncertainElName and @missing-cause]]"
        mode="missing"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfFirstPass)/*" mode="pass2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@missing-cause]"/>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="missing">
    <xsl:element name="{$pUncertainElName}">
        <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="outerElement/innerElement" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
    "string-length(substring-before($pOrderedNames,
                                    concat('|', name(), '|')
                                    )
                  )"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The purpose is to add missing Elements add specific places that are missing in the source document. The sourcedocument looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
  <outerElement>
    <innerElement>
      <first>
        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </first>
      <second missing-cause="bla" />
      <third>
        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
      </third>
    </innerElement>
  </outerElement>
</doc>
```

I have to add a lot of elements like this in a similar way so I want to use parameters to specify the parents path and the element I want to insert.

So here comes the first question: How do I use a parameter in a match? match="$parameter" or variants do not seem to work.

And the second one:
There is still a problem with adding the element with this template which i think comes from the second pass.

If my document does look like posted above it flattens the output to

```
<doc>
  <outerElement>Some TextSome TextINSERTED BY TEMPLATE</outerElement>
</doc>
```

if the  is missing its working as it should. There is missing something most likely in the buildup of the second path but i can't figure out how to fix this.

And the last.. Is it ok to call this template with different parameters like 20 times on a single document to transform it or should i try something else?

Thanks for help again and sorry I am new to this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 it isn't possible to evaluate an XPath expression dynamically.

Therefore, what you attempt to do with `$pParentPath` will not produce the desired result.

As a workaround you may pass two different parameters: `pchildName` and `pgrandchildName` and use something like this:

```
*[name()=$pchildName]/*[name()=$pgrandchildName]
```

In XSLT 1.0 a variable or parameter reference is forbidden in a match pattern. In XSLT 2.0 it is OK.

**Here is the transformation, corrected to work on this specific XML document:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pUncertainElName" select="'second'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|first|second|third|'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerElement">
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfFirstPass">
          <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=
            "self::*[not(*[name() = $pUncertainElName])
                    or
                    *[name()=$pUncertainElName and @missing-cause]]"
            mode="missing"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfFirstPass)/*" mode="pass2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@missing-cause]"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="missing">
        <xsl:element name="{$pUncertainElName}">
            <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerElement" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "string-length(substring-before($pOrderedNames,
                                        concat('|', name(), '|')
                                        )
                      )"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <innerElement>
            <first>
                <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
            </first>
            <second missing-cause="bla" />
            <third>
                <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
            </third>
        </innerElement>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <innerElement>
         <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
         </first>
         <second>
            <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
         </second>
         <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
         </third>
      </innerElement>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**The transformation can be modified so that it processes the children of different elements at different locations of the document hierarchy**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pUncertainElName" select="'second'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|first|second|third|'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfFirstPass">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfFirstPass)/*" mode="pass2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerElement">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=
            "self::*[not(*[name() = $pUncertainElName])
                    or
                    *[name()=$pUncertainElName and @missing-cause]]"
            mode="missing"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@missing-cause]"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="missing">
        <xsl:element name="{$pUncertainElName}">
            <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerElement" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "string-length(substring-before($pOrderedNames,
                                        concat('|', name(), '|')
                                        )
                      )"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (containing two `innerElement` elements -- with different parents and at different depths -- whose children need the specialized processing):

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <innerElement>
            <first>
                <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
            </first>
            <second missing-cause="bla" />
            <third>
                <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
            </third>
        </innerElement>
        <outerElement2>
          <outerElement3>
            <innerElement>
                    <first>
                        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
                    </first>
                    <third>
                        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
                    </third>
            </innerElement>
          </outerElement3>
        </outerElement2>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <innerElement>
         <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
         </first>
         <second>
            <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
         </second>
         <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
         </third>
      </innerElement>
      <outerElement2>
         <outerElement3>
            <innerElement>
               <first>
                  <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
               </first>
               <second>
                  <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
               </second>
               <third>
                  <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
               </third>
            </innerElement>
         </outerElement3>
      </outerElement2>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**Finally, we can modify the transformation even further, so that it can process the children of differently named parents -- say `innerElement` and `someOtherInnerElement`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pUncertainElName" select="'second'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pOrderedNames" select="'|first|second|third|'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfFirstPass">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfFirstPass)/*" mode="pass2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerElement | someOtherInnerElement">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=
            "self::*[not(*[name() = $pUncertainElName])
                    or
                    *[name()=$pUncertainElName and @missing-cause]]"
            mode="missing"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@missing-cause]"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="missing">
        <xsl:element name="{$pUncertainElName}">
            <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="innerElement | someOtherInnerElement" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "string-length(substring-before($pOrderedNames,
                                        concat('|', name(), '|')
                                        )
                      )"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document, where the children to be processed in the required way have parents named with these two names ( `innerElement` and `someOtherInnerElement`):**

```
<doc>
    <outerElement>
        <innerElement>
            <first>
                <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
            </first>
            <second missing-cause="bla" />
            <third>
                <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
            </third>
        </innerElement>
        <outerElement2>
          <outerElement3>
            <someOtherInnerElement>
                    <first>
                        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
                    </first>
                    <third>
                        <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
                    </third>
            </someOtherInnerElement>
          </outerElement3>
        </outerElement2>
    </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<doc>
   <outerElement>
      <innerElement>
         <first>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
         </first>
         <second>
            <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
         </second>
         <third>
            <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
         </third>
      </innerElement>
      <outerElement2>
         <outerElement3>
            <someOtherInnerElement>
               <first>
                  <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
               </first>
               <second>
                  <CharacterString>INSERTED BY TEMPLATE</CharacterString>
               </second>
               <third>
                  <textElement>Some Text</textElement>
               </third>
            </someOtherInnerElement>
         </outerElement3>
      </outerElement2>
   </outerElement>
</doc>
```

**Explanation**:

This is essentially the same logic as for the previous question:

1. Two-pass processing.
2. Overriding the identity rule.
3. Proper use of templates and template match-patterns.
4. Sorting elements by the preferred order of their names.

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answers :) That i cant evaluate XPaths dynamically is not cool but i think ill have to live with that. The workaround works so far. What i wonder about is why does match="outerElement/innerElement" produces a flattened output when sorting while match="innerElement" does not?

Comment: The main problem that still remains is that i have to specify full paths because some Elements are redundant (The schema is not changeable) so if i always match innerElement and do changes there this has side effects to all innerElements while i only want to change that with a specific path.

Comment: @DennisIch: What must be specified as a template match pattern is the shortest (in number of location steps) possible relative path that uniquely identifies the node to be matched. More than one such paths can be combined using the union operator (`|`) -- therefore the required processing can still be concentrated in a single template.

Comment: Well that does not make me happy so far xD. Is it possible to do a variant where i get an xpath with the parent element i want to change and then select it as a node set without match and then use xsl:calltemplate to call the first pass? I know i could use | to match different ones but they are sometimes very similar and sometimes the paths differ. The elements i want to change are sometimes prototypes for several others in the document which right now get changed too specifing all the paths with each element individual which i have to create and its path i would need alot of variants from

Comment: the original template even with the | operator because so much different similar elements with different names have to be added on very different paths :) - I see the match clause does not work with dynamic xPaths but i found the dynamic:evaluate module which also does not work in match... But with it it should be possible to use my idea with calltemplate ?

Comment: @DennisIch: DYnamic evaluation will possibly be available in XSLT 3.0. However, I think it most probably isn't necessary. One can: a) generate a new stylesheet; b) load the stylesheet as an XML document and use the DOM methods to modify the values of the wanted attributes -- then execute the updated transformation. This is essentially how the XPath Visualizer works -- you can have a look at its source code here: http://huttar.net/dimitre/TopXML-XPV.html