# parse xml string with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML with an XML string inside

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><body xmlns:ns0="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/sibx/ServiceGateway" xmlns:ns1="http://com.ibm.websphere.jms.data.bindings/schema">
  <ns0:JMSTextBody_element>
    <ns1:value>&lt;delivery gduid="6395" sduid="2392"&gt;&#13;
    &lt;object type="issue" id="C0.ISS.1451" alt_id="BBG000BH7B07"&gt;&#13;
        &lt;attributes&gt;&#13;
            &lt;simple id="bb_global_id" changed="true"&gt;BBG000BH7B07&lt;/simple&gt;&#13;
            &lt;simple id="dv_source1" changed="true"&gt;BB&lt;/simple&gt;&#13;
            &lt;simple id="nominal_value" changed="true"&gt;0.1&lt;/simple&gt;&#13;
        &lt;/attributes&gt;&#13;
    &lt;/object&gt;&#13;
&lt;/delivery&gt;</ns1:value>
  </ns0:JMSTextBody_element>
</body>
```

I need to fetch the values from the inline XML reformat and create a new XML string

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><body xmlns:ns0="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/sibx/ServiceGateway" xmlns:ns1="http://com.ibm.websphere.jms.data.bindings/schema">
  <ns0:JMSTextBody_element>
    <ns1:value>
 <ac_connect_type>issue</ac_connect_type><ac_connect_id>C0.ISS.1451</ac_connect_id><ac_connect_alt_id>BBG000BH7B07</ac_connect_alt_id><bb_global_id>BBG000BH7B07</bb_global_id>
 <dv_source1>BB</dv_source1><nominal_value>0.1</nominal_value></ns1:value>
  </ns0:JMSTextBody_element>
</body>
```

I'm having trouble to get to the elements in the inline XML

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/delivery/object/attributes/bb_global_id" />
```

doesn't seem to work, obviously I'm missing something here
Thanks

Comment: Can you use Saxon 9.6 (HE should suffice) or one of the commercial editions of Saxon 9.5? That way you could use the `parse-xml` function respectively a Saxon extension to parse the content of `ns1:value` as XML and then you can apply-templates. Or look into the documentation of your favorite XSLT processor whether it has an extension or allows you to implement one to parse a string of XML into a document.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Saxon 9.6 and XSLT 3.0 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ns1="http://com.ibm.websphere.jms.data.bindings/schema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:value">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(.)//object"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , attributes/simple"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object/@*">
  <xsl:element name="ac_connect_{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="simple">
  <xsl:element name="{@id}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which creates the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:ns0="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/sibx/ServiceGateway"
      xmlns:ns1="http://com.ibm.websphere.jms.data.bindings/schema">
   <ns0:JMSTextBody_element>
      <ns1:value>
         <ac_connect_type>issue</ac_connect_type>
         <ac_connect_id>C0.ISS.1451</ac_connect_id>
         <ac_connect_alt_id>BBG000BH7B07</ac_connect_alt_id>
         <bb_global_id>BBG000BH7B07</bb_global_id>
         <dv_source1>BB</dv_source1>
         <nominal_value>0.1</nominal_value>
      </ns1:value>
   </ns0:JMSTextBody_element>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the elegant solution, but I can only use xslt 2.0

Comment: Most XSLT 2.0 processors come with an extension function similar to `parse-xml` or allow you to implement one so you will need to check which XSLT 2.0 processor you use and which extensions or extension implementation features it offers.

Answer (score 1):

> obviously I'm missing something here

It seems you're missing the fact that the escaped XML inside `ns1:value` is just a meaningless string, and cannot be addressed using XPath.

The "correct" solution is to make the transformation in two passes. In the first pass, use:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/sibx/ServiceGateway" xmlns:ns1="http://com.ibm.websphere.jms.data.bindings/schema">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:JMSTextBody_element/ns1:value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Save the result of this transformation to a file, then apply another transformation, using another stylesheet, to that file.

Alternatively, you could try and extract the required information from the escaped string using string functions - which is awkward and error-prone.

Comment: .. and probably not very efficient doing substring-before/after operations all the time. Actually I wanted to avoid any 2 step approach.

Comment: @FreshMike "*I wanted to avoid any 2 step approach*". Of course it's more convenient if you *can* avoid it, but it's not something you should reject on principle - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528783/removing-attributes-from-xslt-and-working-with-result-set/6532681#6532681