# Transform XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have the following XML sample:

```
<finding>
    <title>Found something</title>
    <heading>Severity:</heading>
    <text>Really low.</text>
    <heading>URL:</heading>
    <text>https://www.something.com:443</text>
    <heading>Description:</heading>
    <text>We have found an issue</text>
    <heading>Impact:</heading>
    <text>This is bad.</text>
    <heading>Recommendations:</heading>
    <text>Fix it!.</text>
</finding>
```

Is this easily done with an XSLT? I am using Python with lxml if that helps. 
What I would like to have is an XSLT that will give me the following:

```
<finding>
    <title>Found something</title>
    <severity>Really low.</severity>
    <url>https://www.something.com:443</url>
    <description>We have found an issue</description>
    <impact>This is bad.</impact>
    <recommendations>Fix it!</recommendations>
</finding>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes - I think that XSLT is good choice!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that processes correctly even such `<heading>` elements, that contain arbitrary non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT would be a fairly decent way to do it. The selector for the `text` nodes is a little complex, but a template along the following lines should do it (just add modified versions of this for your other headings).

```
<xsl:template match="text[preceding-sibling::heading[1][text()='Description:']]">
    <description><xsl:value-of select="." /></description>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the [identity stylesheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) is probably a reasonable starting point for adding your templates to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three templates:

First, the [**identity transformation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e17557) template to copy all nodes as is

Then, two rules overriding the required elements as follows:

```
 <xsl:template match="finding/heading">
  <xsl:element name="{lower-case(substring-before(.,':'))}">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text[1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="finding/*[not(self::heading or self::title)]"/>
```

where `lower-case()` is XPath 2.0 function. For XPath 1.0 *lower-case* handling you can see the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518268/converting-xml-node-names-to-uppercase-xslt-1-0/6518635#6518635).

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0 :

```
<!-- Identity Template / Copy by default -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="heading">
    <xsl:element name="{lower-case(replace(., ':', ''))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text[1]"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text"/>
```

Give you the exact output.

Comment: See empo's solution for the use of "substring-before" instead of "replace". Much better in this case, for performance and compatibility with XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation correctly processes even documents in which `<heading>` contains arbitrary non-alphanumeric characters**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
  "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select=
  "'0123456789'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlhpaNum" select=
  "concat($vUpper, $vLower, $vDigits)"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[not(self::heading or self::text)]|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="heading">
  <xsl:element name=
  "{translate(translate(.,translate(.,$vAlhpaNum,''),''),
              $vUpper,
              $vLower
             )
   }">
   <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text[1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one, but made more challenging):

```
<finding>
    <title>Found something</title>
    <heading>Severity...</heading>
    <text>Really low.</text>
    <heading>URL?</heading>
    <text>https://www.something.com:443</text>
    <heading>Description:</heading>
    <text>We have found an issue</text>
    <heading>Impact!:</heading>
    <text>This is bad.</text>
    <heading>Recommendations!!!</heading>
    <text>Fix it!.</text>
</finding>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<finding>
   <title>Found something</title>
   <severity>Really low.</severity>
   <url>https://www.something.com:443</url>
   <description>We have found an issue</description>
   <impact>This is bad.</impact>
   <recommendations>Fix it!.</recommendations>
</finding>
```